# Should an edit notice be in plural when mentioning multiple document titles?

Tags: style, grammar, titles

I'm sending a message to a group of people informing them of an edit to one of their documents now mentions a reference to multiple documents and their titles. There is a total of four documents with four different titles.
Should I write either:

- the documents titles
- the document titles
- or the titles of each document

Which would be most grammatically correct?

Comment: I would recommend bullet three since it's more specific. Bullet one seems like vague info and bullet two doesn't have the plural 'S' behind the word 'document'.

Comment: Bullet one is missing an apostrophe.

Comment: Questions about grammar are off-topic. https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

You should better go with "the titles of each document"! Its sounds okay and looks **Professional**

Comment: Why do think it looks professional?  It would make a much better answer if you explained that.

Comment: *the titles of each document* might look professional but it would only be correct if each document had multiple titles.  More usually each document would have only one title and one would write *the title of each document*.